# Reference for very basic books in Functional analysis

Tags: functional-analysis, book-recommendation

I'm confused about which books I have to read for Functional analysis for the beginner level.

I need references for  very basic books  in Functional analysis and that book  must contain given Topics below

$1.$ Normed linear spaces,

$2.$ Banach spaces,

$3.$ Hilbert spaces,

$4.$ Compact operators.

$5.$ Properties  of $ C[0;1]$ and $L^p[0;1]$

$6.$ Continuous linear maps (linear operators).

$7.$ Hahn-Banach Theorem, Open mapping theorem,

$8.$ Closed graph theorem and the uniform boundedness principle.

Comment: Kreyszig: Introductory Functional Analysis with Applications.

Comment: Pretty much any introductory functional analysis textbook will cover these topics. Personally one I really like (and  where I first learnt functional analysis myself) is Bhatia's 'Notes on functional analysis'. It is written in the format of lectures so it feels like following a university course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My top two recommendations would be [Functional Analysis: A First Course](https://books.google.de/books?id=im0engEACAAJ&printsec=copyright&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false) by M.T Nair (very beginner friendly) and [Introductory Functional Analysis with Applications](https://books.google.de/books/about/Introductory_Functional_Analysis_With_Ap.html?id=Va8rAAAAYAAJ&redir_esc=y) by E. Kreyszig.

I also recommend the notes by [V. S. Sunder](https://www.imsc.res.in/~sunder/fa.pdf) for more of a spectral theoretic focus. You can also check out [Functional Analysis](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9789386279422) by S. Kesavan.

Answer (score 2):

As @Jan mentioned in the comments, Kreyszig's text on functional analysis is a great introduction and has all the topics that you're looking for. It also has a great deal of applications which other texts seem to ignore. However, it does not cover the measure theoretic aspects of the theory.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [A Friendly Approach to Functional Analysis](https://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/q0096) by A. Sasane?

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. Could you edit your post to include the main idea provided by the article? Link only answer are viewed as a bad answer since link could be lost.